# Alternative to httpConnection.getContentLength()?

Tags: android

I call the following function to get the total files size to download:

```
private Uri askForFileSizeFromURL(URL url, String fileName) {
    try {
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = conn instanceof HttpURLConnection ? (HttpURLConnection ) conn  : null;
        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

            bytesToDownload += httpConnection.getContentLength();

            return null;
        }
    }
    catch(ConnectException e) {
        Log.d("2ndGuide", "ConnectException." + e);
        downloadAborted = true;
        return null;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("2ndGuide", "IO Exception." + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm calling this function 31 times and it takes more than 23 secondes. Without this call the loop takes 320ms. So the problem comes from this code.

Is there a quicker way to get files size from a remote server on Internet?

Regards,
Alain

Comment: use HEAD instead GET or store the size with url (i mean how get the the urls? some json? then add property size like `[...,{"name":"NameOfTheURL", "URL": "scheme://some/url", "size": 666}, ...]`

Comment: @Selvin. Sorry, I don't really understand. Do you mean getHeaderFieldxxx()? I get the list of urls from an xml file, but it's quite difficult for me to record the file size in this xml file.

Comment: In fact according to deeper investigation, it's maybe not so long in fact. mean values are: 09-03 18:35:28.962: I/url.openConnection() (ms)(8309): 11 ms
09-03 18:35:29.602: I/httpConnection.getResponseCode() (ms)(8309): 650 ms
09-03 18:35:29.602: I/httpConnection.getContentLength() (ms)(8309): 0 ms

Comment: I was thinking about setRequestMethod

Comment: @Selvin, ok but in fact, as said in my previous command, the connection process is responsible of the spent time.